# PHP Twitter Bot (ConceptScript)

Tags: php, api, twitter, bots

Twitter has changed its script basics from API 1.0 to API 1.1 making things more difficult.

original API 1.0 code being used was

[code]

```
require_once('twitteroauth.php');

define('CONSUMER_KEY', '//');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '//');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', '//');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', '//');


$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$twitter->host = "http://search.twitter.com/";
$search = $twitter->get('search',array('q' => 'from:eurogamer, OR from:nintendolife, OR from:outsidexbox, OR from:xbox, OR from:OXMUK, OR from:playstationEU, OR from:gamespotuk', 'rrp' => 4));


$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
foreach($search->results as $tweet) {
$status = 'RT @'.$tweet->from_user.' '.$tweet->text;
if(strlen($status) > 140) $status = substr($status, 0, 139);
$twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));
}

echo "Success! Check your twitter bot for retweets!";
```

[/code]

now one user was very helpful and tried to crack the API 1.1 configuration but the attempt did not work

API 1.1 code attempt

[code]

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
$search = $twitter->get('search/tweets',
                    array('q' => 'from:eurogamer OR from:nintendolife OR from:outsidebox',
                          'count' => 4)
                   );

$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
foreach($search->results as $tweet) {
$status = 'RT @'.$tweet->from_user.' '.$tweet->text;
if(strlen($status) > 140) $status = substr($status, 0, 139);
$twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));
}

echo "Success! Check your twitter bot for retweets!";
```

[/code]

so I tried to have my own crack at  it with a idea I came up with last night to conquer the API 1.1 system using the basics of the above code but still to no success

[code]

```
require_once('twitteroauth.php');

define('CONSUMER_KEY', '//');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '//');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', '//');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', '//');
$notweets = 4;


$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40eurogamer%20%40nintendolife%20%40outsidexbox%20%40xbox%20%40OXMUK%20%40playstationEU%20%40gamespotuk."&count=".$notweets);


$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
$status = 'RT @'.$tweet->from_user.' '.$tweet->text;
if(strlen($status) > 140) $status = substr($status, 0, 139);
$twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));
}


echo "Success! Check your twitter bot for retweets!";
```

[/code]

this particular concept above does have an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' on line 12

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse error stems from...

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40eurogamer%20%40nintendolife%20%40outsidexbox%20%40xbox%20%40OXMUK%20%40playstationEU%20%40gamespotuk."&count=".$notweets);
```

should be... (pay attention to the end of the URL)

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40eurogamer%20%40nintendolife%20%40outsidexbox%20%40xbox%20%40OXMUK%20%40playstationEU%20%40gamespotuk&count=".$notweets);
```